# Fitch-Style Proof Help

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm having some trouble solving a Fitch Proof, Here's how far I've gotten.

[image]

Any Help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, so I can't try to save your proof without understanding you. Your goal is $\forall x\left(\left(\text{Large}(x)\lor \text{Cube}(x)\right)\to \text{Dodec}(x)\right)$. The natural thing to do (for me at least) is to take a constant $a$ such that $\left(\text{Large}(a)\lor \text{Cube}(a)\right)$ and try to infer $\text{Dodec}(a)$. You haven't done this. So I ask you, what's your idea with the assumptions at steps 3. and 7.?

Comment: I am trying to get Large(a) v Cube(a) → Dodec(a) is that possible or am I completely off track?

Comment: It certainly is possible. At least you're being to asked to prove that. I just don't see how you intend to go there with your try. I will leave the layout of a proof in an answer,which hopefully you'll be able to formalize. Then I'll be off to bed.

Comment: If this were a question in propositional calculus, then the use of the universal quantifier would come as quantifying over the domain of truth values.  You *can* do this, however, your problem almost surely does not concern the propositional calculus with quantifiers, but rather predicate calculus.

Comment: http://forums.philosophyforums.com/comments.php?id=66868&findpost=1206574#post1206574

Answer (score 2):

I don't get how you intend to go from what you've done to the goal. Let me suggest a different approach.

Your goal is $\forall x\left(\left(\text{Large}(x)\lor \text{Cube}(x)\right)\to \text{Dodec}(x)\right)$.

It's reasonable to take a constant $a$ such that $\text{Large}(a)\lor \text{Cube}(a)$.

Just because it is allowed, I suggest eliminating $\forall$ from the premises with $a$.

Now performing $\lor$-$\text{Elim}$ on $\text{Large}(a)\lor \text{Cube}(a)$ is one way to go.

If $\text{Large}(a)$ holds, then $\text{Dodec}(a)$ follows from the second premise (not exactly, but close enough).

If $\text{Cube}(a)$ holds, you can get a contradiction from the first premise and you can infer whatever you want, namely $\text{Dodec}(a)$.

Eliminating the disjunction and tying loose ends finalizes the proof.

Hover your mouse over the grey area below to see the suggested proof.

> [image: Formal proof]